# Link idp to existing Keycloak account, federated_identity_account_exists error

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-services, idp

In my app the user accounts are created beforehand and are persisted on Keycloak. The problem is that I can not get the idp (google) to automatically link to existing accounts.

Everytime I try to login with one I get a `token exchange error: federated_identity_account_exists`. I checked the users in keycloak and they are not duplicated and idp is also not linked. I have been scratching my head for the past couple of hours on this one.

I tried using the first broker login flow on keycloak and also creating my own, but to no avail.
My own flow went something like this

> Create user if unique (alternative)
> Automatically set existing user (alternative)
> but also tried just
> Automatically set existing user (required)

Comment: were you able to find solution on this ?